# Reopen a question edited by me... is that normal?

Tags: discussion

Whenever I can, I welcome new users to correct (edit) their questions, write comments and so on, as I believe it is easier for them to learn from a ready-made example.
I recently edited this question, with no feedback from the OP, and it ended up correctly closed by 5 other users. I agree that in its present form it must remain closed.

The point is that after a month the question ended up being included in my [review queue](https://superuser.com/review/reopen/1033161) to be reopened.

**Is that normal?**
I mean it ended up in the revision queue to be reopened because I changed it.
And then the system proposed to me to judge whether it should be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That question is currently showing up as a review audit candidate which is probably the reason you are seeing it. Choose your actions wisely.

The [question itself](https://superuser.com/questions/1610551/unable-to-get-internet-from-all-computers-connected-to-a-router) is currently closed and deleted.

Comment: Thx. Now I answered (leave close) and saw it was a test. (My first instinct was to skip it because I was directly involved). By the way, is it possible that a question that is queued to be reopened only because I edited, to end up in my review queue?

Comment: I would be surprised to be honest. I suspect that it is simply the fact that it has already been through the [review queue once](https://superuser.com/review/reopen/1025203) with unanimous "leave closed", downvotes and a deletion making it a good candidate for review. No one wanted it, it got more hate than it really warranted and so shows up to an automated system as something "bad" that might be good to test someone with. You just happened to be the someone.